# PHP Convert array data structure to another one when elements belong to the same id index?

Tags: php, data-structures

I need to convert the data structure of $array1 to $array2. How do I club together the cities belonging to same the uid and title?

```
$array1 = [array("uid" => "29",
                 "title" => "Developer",
                 "city" => "Madrid"),
           array("uid" => "29",
                 "title" => "Developer",
                 "city" => "Berlin"),
           array("uid" => "29",
                 "title" => "Developer",
                 "city" => "London"),
           array("uid" => "30",
                 "title" => "Designer",
                 "city" => "Amsterdam"),
           ];

$array2 = [array("title":"Developer",
                 "city" : ["Madrid","Berlin","London"]),
           array("title":"Designer",
                 "city" : ["Amsterdam"])
          ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $src = array(
        array(
            "uid"   => "29",
            "title" => "Developer",
            "city"  => "Madrid"
        ),
        array(
            "uid"   => "29",
            "title" => "Developer",
            "city"  => "Berlin"
        ),
        array(
            "uid"   => "29",
            "title" => "Developer",
            "city"  => "London"
        ),
        array(
            "uid"   => "30",
            "title" => "Designer",
            "city"  => "Amsterdam"
        ),
    );


    /* placeholder for storing final array */
    $out=array();

    /* iterate through source array */
    foreach( $src as $arr ){
        /* for convenience, cast child array as object */
        $obj=(object)$arr;
        $key=$obj->uid;

        /* construct outpur array format & add values from child arrays/objects */
        if( !array_key_exists( $key, $out ) )$out[ $key ]=array();
        if( !array_key_exists( 'title', $out[ $key ] ) )$out[ $key ]['title']=$obj->title;
        if( !array_key_exists( 'city', $out[ $key ] ) ) $out[ $key ]['city']=array();
        $out[ $key ]['city'][]=$obj->city;
    }
    /* this produces an output array keyed by uid */
    printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($out,true));

    /* If the uid keys are not important and should not appear in output */
    $final=array();
    foreach( $out as $uid => $child )$final[]=$child;

    printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($final,true));
```

The output of which is:

```
Array
(
    [29] => Array
        (
            [title] => Developer
            [city] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Madrid
                    [1] => Berlin
                    [2] => London
                )

        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [title] => Designer
            [city] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Amsterdam
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Developer
            [city] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Madrid
                    [1] => Berlin
                    [2] => London
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Designer
            [city] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Amsterdam
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
<?php

$input = [ 
    [
        "uid" => "29",
        "title" => "Developer",
        "city" => "Madrid"
    ], 
    [
        "uid" => "29",
        "title" => "Developer",
        "city" => "Berlin"
    ], 
    [
        "uid" => "29",
        "title" => "Developer",
        "city" => "London"
    ],
    [
        "uid" => "30",
        "title" => "Designer",
        "city" => "Amsterdam"
    ]
];


$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($entry) use (&$output) {
    if (!array_key_exists($entry["uid"], $output)) {
        $output[$entry["uid"]] = [
            "title" => $entry["title"],
            "city" => [$entry["city"]]
        ];
    } else {
        $output[$entry["uid"]]["city"][] = $entry["city"];
    }
});

var_dump($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
array(2) {
  [29]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Developer"
    ["city"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "Madrid"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "Berlin"
      [2]=>
      string(6) "London"
    }
  }
  [30]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) "Designer"
    ["city"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "Amsterdam"
    }
  }
}
```